# Longest repeating sequence using linq only

Tags: c#, linq, lcs, lrs

As the title says i have a task to find the longest repeating sequence in a string and it has to be done with linq only - no ifs, no loop, no try, assignment is only allowed on initialization of variables, recursion is allowed. I've found the solution online and i understand what is happening but i can't transform it to linq -I'm not that familiar with it. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me.  Here is a link to what ive found  -https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-find-longest-repeating-sequence-in-a-string.

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2};
List<List<int>> aa = new List<List<int>>();
outerLoop(a);

var max = aa.Max(x => x.Count);
var m = from v in aa 
    where v.Count == max
    select v;
    m.Dump();

void outerLoop(List<int> list)
{
List<int> f = new List<int>();
f.AddRange(list.Skip(list.Count-1).Take(list.Count).ToList());
innerLoop(list, list.Skip(1).Take(list.Count).ToList());

f.ForEach(k => outerLoop(list.Skip(1).Take(list.Count).ToList()));
}


void innerLoop(List<int> l, List<int> subList)
{
List<int> f = new List<int>();
f.AddRange(subList.Skip(subList.Count-1).Take(subList.Count).ToList());
var tt = l.TakeWhile((ch, i) => i < subList.Count && subList[i] == ch).ToList();

aa.Add(tt);
f.ForEach(k => innerLoop(l, subList.Skip(1).Take(subList.Count).ToList()));
}
```

so i came up with this "beauty", i don't think it's good code but i think it works. If anyone is interested and wants to make suggestions how to make it better, they are more than welcome to :)

if input is `int[] x= {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}`
result should be `1212`

Comment: You may create linq function?

Comment: @Daniel welcome to SO, unfortunately SO is not a code writing service, if you post your existing code, ie what you have tried, then others might be able to help you better.

Comment: @mxmissile updated, and you know you could have just pointed me to an useful tutorial or something and not get passive aggressive immediately considering ive admitted to not knowing a lot in this subject. Thanks for the tips tho

Comment: @isaeid i believe so

Comment: Linq has set functions too, like union.

Comment: @isaeid isn't union just going to return a collection of the unique values in both sequences im tring to compare, or im missing the point

Comment: Is this for homework? Have you considered `Enumerable.Range`? My answer has 4 steps: find all the possible subsequences (`Enumerable.Range`,`SelectMany`), count how often they repeat (`SequenceEqual` is helpful) and throw out the ones that appear once, find the maximum length (`Max`) of repeated subsequences, and get all the repeated sequences of that length (`Where`).

Comment: @NetMage yea its for an assignment i have, i got an idea last night and i believe its working (code is not good quality i guess), haven't had the time to try other things

Comment: seems like a homework question to me. "Has to be linq" why?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
List<int> words = new List<int> { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2 };

string result =
    words
        .Select((c, i) => i)
        .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(1, words.Count - i).Select(j => words.Skip(i).Take(j)), (i, w) => new { i, w })
        .GroupBy(x => String.Join(",", x.w), x => x.i)
        .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any())
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
        .First();
```

That gives me `1,2,1,2`.

If you want one that actually works with strings, try this:

```
var word = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";

string result =
    word
        .Select((c, i) => i)
        .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(1, word.Length - i).Select(j => word.Skip(i).Take(j)), (i, w) => new { i, w })
        .GroupBy(x => new string(x.w.ToArray()), x => x.i)
        .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any())
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
        .First();
```

That gives me `ali`.

---

Here's a slightly more understandable version:

```
var word = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious";

string result =
(
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length)
    from j in Enumerable.Range(1, word.Length - i)
    group i by word.Substring(i, j) into gis
    where gis.Skip(1).Any()
    orderby gis.Key.Length descending
    select gis.Key
).First();
```

Comment: I believe this is working (its getting the correct result when i test it), but i don't understand it well enough to test all cases (code is a bit complicated for me right now, and i find it a bit hard to follow)

Comment: @Daniel - I've added a slightly more understandable version. Let me know if that's better.

Comment: Interesting trick with `.Skip(1).Any()` for `.Count() > 1` but since `Grouping` implements `Count()` efficiently, it may not be better. Also, while trickier, I prefer handling the case of two equal length sequences being returned when they both repeat. Also suggest `Select((c,i) => i)` is a tricky way to say `Enumerable.Range(0, words.Count-1)` though one reference to `words` is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. It isn't a single LINQ expression, but does use only LINQ. It does return all same length subsequences if there are multiple answers. It should work any type of sequence. It was written to only use standard LINQ methods.

It uses `GroupBy` with a string key to implement a sequence `Distinct`. (Because of this trick, lists that contain items with commas might not work right.) In production code, I would use a `Distinct` with an `IEqualityComparer` for sequences based on `SequenceEqual`. It also has a separate step for finding the maximum repeated sequence length and then finding all the matching sequences, in production code I would use a `MaxBy` extension.

Update: Since I was using `GroupBy` for `DistinctBy`, I realized I could just use that to count the subsequence repeats directly rather than search for them.

```
var repeaters = Enumerable.Range(0, words.Count) // starting positions
                       .SelectMany(n => Enumerable.Range(1, (words.Count - n) / 2).Select(l => words.Skip(n).Take(l).ToList())) // subseqs from each starting position
                       .GroupBy(s => String.Join(",", s), (k, sg) => new { seq = sg.First(), Repeats = sg.Count() }) // count each sequence
                       .Where(sr => sr.Repeats > 1) // only keep repeated sequences
                       .Select(sr => sr.seq); // no longer need counts
var maxRepeaterLen = repeaters.Select(ss => ss.Count()).Max(); // find longest repeated sequence's length
var maxLenRepeaters = repeaters.Where(ss => ss.Count() == maxRepeaterLen); // return all sequences matching longest length
```